# AMD Ryzen 5 5600G not working on CentOS 7

Tags: cpu, bios, centos, kernel, amd-ryzen

I have a CentOS 7 install and I moved the disk to a computer with newer processor, the CPU is `AMD Ryzen 5 5600G` (with **included graphics**).

When I try to boot (this disk or a fresh USB install disk with Centos 7) ... I see an error similar to "not able to write to **IOMMU**" then it hangs like in the below image (not my image, but same errors, same motherboard too).

- I tried enabling disabling IOMMU in bios, no luck.
- Tried specifying `amd_iommu=on iommu=pt` in the command line when selecting boot option, didn't help.
- Tried older bios versions down to the first one that added support for this CPU, didn't help.

Some say it **might need a newer kernel ?** If so, how can I update kernel without reinstalling OS ?
I can put the disk in the old computer which would boot fine to run update commands.

**Update:** I updated the kernel to `6.0.3` using `kernel-lt` from `elrepo-kernel`. Now I see the centos "loading" line at the bottom and it stops at the end. Does this indicate it might need a grub update ? How can I tell ? It boots fine in the old computer so maybe that rules out grub problems?

[image]

Comment: It's a 2yo kernel and the latest, take the hit and upgrade.

Comment: I posted an update above, I updated the kernel to `6.0.3`using `kernel-lt` from `elrepo-kernel` but no luck. How can I debug this ? :/

Comment: @Bib did you meant upgrade to CentOS 8/9 ? I thought you meant update/upgrade kernel , I posted this updated question, maybe you have some tips, thank you: https://superuser.com/questions/1749703/how-can-i-install-kernel-5-17-on-centos-7

Comment: Unless you are a company, then upgrade the system. If you are a company then purchase support.