# How can I install Kernel 5.17 on CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, centos, kernel, centos-7, linux-kernel

On a CentOS 7.9 installation I have some troubles running newer CPUs, e.g Ryzen 5 5600G (with included graphics).

I concluded that it is the Kernel because it boots with certain versions, with kernel `5.4.219-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64` for example boots but I see this during boot:

```
kobject: can not set name properly!
mce: Unable to init MCE device (rc: -22)
```

After that it boots OK, only problem I noticed is that text is very large on console screen, so it must be missing some drivers/packages.

I read that kernel 5.17 has some updates for AMD Ryzen CPUs and I am trying to install this one, but I don't know how.

I installed `5.4.219-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64` and `6.0.3-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64` (not booting) from `el-repo` repositories, but I cannot find 5.17 there.

- How / from where can I install `5.17 kernel` or how to know which one is good for this CPU ?
- Is it uncommon to try to install `5.17 kernel` on CentOS 7 and I should move to CentOS 8/9 ?
- Are the above errors not serious and I should stick to `5.4.219-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64` (only kernel that boots) ?

Comment: Yes, you should move to a release which is contemporary of your hardware, i.e., CentOS 9. CentOS 8 is EoL since 2021 so that's out of the question.

Comment: https://www.centos.org/cl-vs-cs/

Comment: Note: if you don't want to change to CentOS Stream - which is now ahead of RHEL development - you may consider changing to another RHEL based distro like AlmaLinux 9 or RockyLinux 9.

Comment: I went for RockyLinux 9, so far so good, better than expected, I thought it is not very known or not very stable, I was wrong :)